# AngularJS Services Using $q or wrapping in returns

Tags: angularjs

I am fairly new to Angular and have seen a few different ways to do many different things.  I try to subscribe to Todd Motto's style guide.  Example 1 is code written by my pairing partner and Example 2 is how I wrote it.

We would appreciate any feedback on wrong or right things either example is doing.

Thanks.

**Example 1**

```
angular
  .module('app.services')
  .service('FriendsService', function($q, $http, Auth){
    var baseUrl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v1.0'

    this.all = function() {
      var defer = $q.defer();
      $http
        .get(baseUrl + '/me/friends', { params: { access_token: Auth.currentUser.accessToken } })
        .then(function(response){
          defer.resolve(response.data.data)
        });

      return defer.promise;
    };
  });
```

**Example 2**

```
angular
  .module('app.services')
  .service('FriendsService', function($http, Auth){
    var baseUrl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v1.0'

    var getAll = function() {
      return $http
            .get(baseUrl + '/me/friends', { params: { access_token: Auth.currentUser.accessToken } })
            .then(function(response){
              return response.data.data;
            });
    };

    return {
      all: getAll
    }
  });
```

**Usage of FriendsService**

```
FriendsService.all()
  .then(function(data){
    $scope.friends = data;      
  });
```

Comment: you might find it easier to just return { all: function () { return $http.get(baseUrl + '/me/friends', { params: { access_token: Auth.currentUser.accessToken } }); } }; from your service, then handling it like you would any $q promise, so in your controller FriendsService.all().then(function (res) { .. }, function (err) { ... });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$http` uses `$q` internally. Effectively the examples are nearly identical.

However, Example 1 doesn't catch any rejections by `$http`. It creates a redundant promise which wraps `$http` incompletely.

Example 2 would generally be preferred.

Comment: I don't think either of them are catching rejections.

Comment: The point is that in Example 2, you could do `FriendsService.all().catch()`.

Comment: The call to `defer()` is not redundant in Example 1, as it is required to create a new deferred promise everytime `all()` is invoked, unless you want all invocations to `all()` be resolved to the very first request you have made with the method call.

Comment: The point there is that `$http` already defers by itself. It is just a redundant 'promisewrapper'.

Comment: What about about the practice of declaring `all`? Personally I prefer the declaration in Example 1.

Comment: In example 2 the service should really be a factory (it returns an object). The usage of service vs factory is typically user preference. Pick one and try to stick to it.

Comment: Thanks for all the input guys!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider error-handling as well. I suggest using a .catch() block, as espoused by K. Scott Allen in his blog post:

http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/04/21/better-error-handling-in-angularjs.aspx

Example:

```
var getAll = function() {
  return $http
    .get(...)
      .then(function(response){
        return response.data;
      })
      .catch(genericErrorHandler(e));
};
```

Note that the calling code will need to check that the value of "data" is not undefined (you can use angular.isDefined() for this).